# Java - abstract class and interface

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

I'm working on my java project which is a basic roleplaying-game, and I have an OOD question (I guess it's pretty simple, but it's my first java project). I started working on weapons, I created an abstract Weapon class with an abstract method named attack. Weapon has two subclasses - MeleeWeapon and RangedWeapon, and both have attack method, and it's fine.

Then I thought about another thing - what would happen if a MeleeWeapon object like spear can be used for close combat and can also be thrown? what would be a good solution in this case?

Comment: Use a Throwable Interface.

Comment: One possible solution: forget about abstract weapons, create a `MeleeWeapon` interface (with a method `meleeAttack`) and a `RangedWeapon` interface (with a method `rangedAttack`). Now a class can implement both interfaces.

Comment: @Turing85 , I thought that interface can help here, but how do I differentiate between a Sword that can be used as a melee weapon and a spear which is a melee and ranged weapon ?

Comment: Another option is to use composition rather than inheritance. Each weapon can *have* a set of attacks. For example, `Weapon.getAttacks()` returns a set of supported attacks. `Spear.getAttacks()` returns Thrust, Throw and BashBashBash.

Comment: @Niminim as I said: each class can now implement both interfaces. Since the names of the interface-methods are not the same (`meleeAttack` and `rangedAttack`, the can be clearly distinguished. Andy Thomas's solution is even more elgant since a weapon could then have multiple ranged or melee attacks.

Comment: It implements both and then throws a Throwable.... : ), sorry could not help myself I don't belive that Throwable is a good name for your interface...

Comment: @PetterFriberg to create a Future in the future ;)?

Comment: @Turing85, ok, I got it, it's a good solution :)

Comment: @AndyThomas , your solution also sounds good :)

Comment: I think I'm gonna try the two approaches for the the sake of exercise and to get some new insights :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use composition rather than inheritance.

Each weapon can offer a set of attacks. For example, `Weapon.getAttacks()` returns a set of supported attacks. In the subclass, `Spear.getAttacks()` returns instances of `Thrust`, `Throw` and `BashBashBash`.

This allows you to use the same attack with multiple weapons. Both a mace and a spear could offer a Bash attack -- just with different HP damage. You could Thrust with a spear or a 10-foot-pole. You could Throw a spellbook. (And those things hurt more than you might think.) In general, you can define the results of any action with any object.

Comment: I thought you meant in the first message to use just a Weapon class, so each weapon will have a list of available attacks like throw and thrust (which will be methods in Weapon class).

Comment: Now, I understand that you suggest to create Thrust and Throw classes, right ? can you give a short implementation example of how to deal with Thrust and Throw classes ?

Comment: Right, weapons are objects that have attacks like Thrust and Throw, in addition to other attributes. A Weapon subclass like Spear could initialize the weapon's attacks in a constructor, passing appropriate ranges for damage. The `attack()` method you cite could be a method within the *attack* class, rather than the weapon class. For polymorphism, you'll want a superclass AbstractAttack that provides an abstract `attack()` method.

Comment: I think I lost you, Andy :)  You suggest to create Weapon class, and create a new class for each weapon ? I can easily end up with lots of classes just for the weapons...why do you suggest using attack method in Attack class, why do I need an Attack class? and where Thrust and Throw fit here ?

Comment: Regarding my misunderstanding of the necessity of Throw and Thrust classes - I think about throwing and thrusting as actions (methods) , maybe it can help you understand my POV, so you can explain it better

Comment: One option is for Weapon to be an abstract class, with subclasses that configure the attacks for specific weapon types. Another is for there to be one WeaponType class with one object per type of weapon. An abstract base class for attacks allows you to define and interact with specific attacks through a standard interface. Methods execute actions, but you can represent an action as an object that offers a method to execute the action; sometimes these are called *function objects*.

Comment: The key thing here is to identify an `Attack`. (a DDD approach). Then You will soon find that it's not the weapon that attacks but someone/something who uses it. Then You will see something like `AttackSource` which generates `Attacks` and `AttackTarget` which accepts attacks. Eg. trap can be an attack source. And eg. door, enemy, wall are valid attack targets. A hero can wield many `AttackSource`s  etc. This will open a lot of new possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of interface and composition, both offer very well documented solutions.  But I have a third idea: just add throw() to MeleeWeapon.  Hear me out, if you use interface it will make it harder to randomly generate weapons.  If you use composition you have to start over and create throw and melee objects inside your weapon.  Sometimes the easiest answer is the way to go, especially since you can now refer to your melee or ranged object by their parent class and call their throw method without worry.

Comment: Yeah, it also sounds like a good idea, and probably the easiest :) . but wouldn't it produce a duplicate code ? I mean that RangedWeapon will have attack, and throw in MeleeWeapon will be identical to attack method in RangedWeapon class. Any change in RangedWeapon's attack method would require me to change throw in MeleeWeapon.

Comment: I assumed the melee throw would be different from the ranged attack (lose your weapon for a turn or damage calculations). If they are the exact same method write the ranged attack method in the parent class. The melee weapon would overwrite this with its melee attack and could have a throw method which only calls super.attack() to get the ranged version.

Comment: I haven't fully thought about it. Maybe throwing a dagger would be identical to shot with a bow, but different than throwing a spear.

Comment: Your solution is very practical and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces seam like the best approach:

**Concept**

Maybe make your `Weapon` class a bit more abstract: only the basic methods required(attack, drop, ect.). Maybe even make it non abstract so that it works out of the box.

Now for special functionality make some interfaces that allow things like throw, shoot, explode, ect. This way adding new functionality to a weapon will be a lot easier and less time consuming.

Now when the attack function is called, it can do completely different kinds of attacks based on what interfaces the weapon class implements.

**Design**

Base class:

```
//the general weapon class
public class Weapon{

   //you don't want your base class instantiatable 
   protected Weapon(){}

    public void attack (){
        //take enemy health ect.
    }

    public void drop(){
        //drop weapon
     }
}
```

What you could do with the interfaces is make the method return true if the enemy can be hit, or from within the method call the attack function if the enemy can be hit.

Melee interface:

```
public interface Melee {
    boolean onMelee();//called if the player tries to perform a melee attack
}
```

Ranged interface:

```
public interface Ranged {
    boolean onRanged();//called if the player tries to perform a ranged attack
}
```

Bow weapon class:

```
public class WeaponBow extends Weapon implements Ranged{

    @Override
    public boolean onRanged(){
        //play animation, check if target is vulnerable, ect.
        //return true if the enemy can be hit false otherwise
    }
}
```

Now when the player tries to use the weapon to attack, the application can check if the weapon class implements those interfaces and then call the appropriate method.

If a weapon class extends more than one interface, a good way to figure out which action to take may be to have a selection of possible actions, if the player has ranged selected then try preform the ranged attack. If the player for instance has melee selected but it's a ranged weapon then the default or only other available attack should be called.